# In an interface, toggle between two types if another property is `true` or `false`

Tags: typescript

Ok, so I don't know if this is possible but basically I have an interface which accepts two properties: `loggedIn` (`boolean`) and `username` (`string | null`). Is it possible to make the interface accept `string` for `username` only if `loggedIn` is `true` (and `null` if it's `false`)?

This isn't some valid Typescript code but maybe it will give you a better understanding:

```js
interface State {
  loggedIn: boolean;
  username: State['loggedIn'] ? string : null;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible the way you wrote, because types are checked before values are set. What *is* possible is to say you have *two* interfaces, i.e.

```
interface LoggedInState {
    loggedIn: true;
    username: string;
}

interface LoggedOutState {
    loggedIn: false;
    username: null;
}

type UserLoginState = LoggedInState | LoggedOutState;
```

And then use that type. The important distinction between your intuition and this approach to remember is that type checking happens before your code is ever run.

Comment: This is nice. I haven't thought about "interface matching". Thanks you!

Comment: Sure thing. Please accept unless you'd like me to expound any further?

Comment: Yes sorry. I have forgotten.

Comment: No worries, ty :-)